# Issue in php json formatting

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am currently stuck in json formatting for php. I have given my outputted json below. What I need to do is to make the format of the current json to the desired one. I am missing the arrays in the JSON format. Can anyone help me on this.

My code to print the json output is below:

```
$menuHead=array(); 
$i=0; 
foreach($res as $key => $value){ 
    $i=$key+1;
    //$menuHead[$i]['menuHead']=$value['category'];
    if(isset($menuHead[$key]['menuHead'])){
        if($menuHead[$key]['menuHead']==$value['category']){
          $menuHead[$key]['data'][$i]['itemName']=$value['sub_category'];
          $menuHead[$key]['data'][$i]['price']=$value['price'];
          $menuHead[$key]['data'][$i]['description']=$value['description'];
          $menuHead[$key]['data'][$i]['itemId']=$value['id'];
          $menuHead[$key]['data'][$i]['customizable']=$value['customizable'];
        }else{
          $menuHead[$i]['menuHead']=$value['category'];
          $menuHead[$i]['data'][$i]['itemName']=$value['sub_category'];  
          $menuHead[$i]['data'][$i]['price']=$value['price'];
          $menuHead[$i]['data'][$i]['description']=$value['description'];
          $menuHead[$i]['data'][$i]['itemId']=$value['id'];
          $menuHead[$i]['data'][$i]['customizable']=$value['customizable'];
        }
    }else{
      $menuHead[$i]['menuHead']=$value['category'];
      $menuHead[$i]['data'][$i]['itemName']=$value['sub_category'];  
      $menuHead[$i]['data'][$i]['price']=$value['price'];
      $menuHead[$i]['data'][$i]['description']=$value['description'];
      $menuHead[$i]['data'][$i]['itemId']=$value['id'];
      $menuHead[$i]['data'][$i]['customizable']=$value['customizable'];
    }    
}
$final['MenuList']=$menuHead;
echo json_encode($final);
```

Current format:

```
    {
  "MenuList": {
    "1": {
      "menuHead": "Main Course",
      "data": {
        "1": {
          "itemName": "Chicken Thai Curry",
          "price": "599",
          "description": "",
          "itemId": "67",
          "customizable": "1"
        }
      }
    },
    "2": {
      "menuHead": "Refreshments",
      "data": {
        "2": {
          "itemName": "Kingfisher Premium",
          "price": "999",
          "description": "Kingfisher beer",
          "itemId": "69",
          "customizable": "1"
        },
        "3": {
          "itemName": "Mocktail",
          "price": "999",
          "description": "",
          "itemId": "68",
          "customizable": "1"
        }
      }
    },
    "4": {
      "menuHead": "Rice biriyani",
      "data": {
        "4": {
          "itemName": "Dal makni risotto",
          "price": "499",
          "description": "Dal makhni risotto",
          "itemId": "66",
          "customizable": "1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Desired Format:

```
    {
  "menuList": [
    {
      "menuHead": "In Steamer (Momos)",
      "data": [
        {
          "itemName": "Tandoori Momo",
          "description": "",
          "price": "150",
          "itemId": "16",
          "customizable": "0"
        },
        {
          "itemName": "Fried Momo Pork",
          "price": "100",
          "description": "",
          "itemId": "15",
          "customizable": "0"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "itemName": "Rice and Noodles",
      "data": [
        {
          "sub_category": "Tandoori Momo",
          "description": "",
          "price": "150",
          "itemId": "16",
          "customizable": "0"
        },
        {
          "itemName": "Fried Momo Pork",
          "price": "100",
          "description": "",
          "itemId": "15",
          "customizable": "0"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Raw response is below:

array(4) { [0]=> array(7) { ["id"]=> string(2) "67" ["restaurant_id"]=> string(1) "5" ["category"]=> string(11) "Main Course" ["sub_category"]=> string(18) "Chicken Thai Curry" ["price"]=> string(3) "599" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["customizable"]=> string(1) "1" } [1]=> array(7) { ["id"]=> string(2) "69" ["restaurant_id"]=> string(1) "5" ["category"]=> string(12) "Refreshments" ["sub_category"]=> string(18) "Kingfisher Premium" ["price"]=> string(3) "999" ["description"]=> string(15) "Kingfisher beer" ["customizable"]=> string(1) "1" } [2]=> array(7) { ["id"]=> string(2) "68" ["restaurant_id"]=> string(1) "5" ["category"]=> string(12) "Refreshments" ["sub_category"]=> string(8) "Mocktail" ["price"]=> string(3) "999" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["customizable"]=> string(1) "1" } [3]=> array(7) { ["id"]=> string(2) "66" ["restaurant_id"]=> string(1) "5" ["category"]=> string(13) "Rice biriyani" ["sub_category"]=> string(17) "Dal makni risotto" ["price"]=> string(3) "499" ["description"]=> string(18) "Dal makhni risotto" ["customizable"]=> string(1) "1" } }

Comment: Arrays start at 0!

Answer (score 3):

If you want a javascript compatible array, the index must start at 0. The easiest way to do that, is to use [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php):

```
$final['MenuList'] = array_values($menuHead);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when your adding the `data` items, you need to add them without specific keys, as you add them with `$i` as in...

```
  $menuHead[$key]['data'][$i]['itemName']=$value['sub_category'];
```

This will stop them being a normal array as you want it to be.  For `json_encode()` an array must start at 0 and be sequential for it to be an array.

Instead create them in one go and add them to the end of the existing data using `[]`...

```
  $menuHead[$key]['data'][] = ['itemName' =>$value['sub_category'],
                  'price'=> $value['price'],
                  'description'=>$value['description'],
                  'itemId'=>$value['id'],
                  'customizable'=>$value['customizable']];
```

This needs to be done with each set of similar code, which includes the overall array itself, this can be done using

```
$final['MenuList'] = array_values($menuHead);
```

To try and fix the data you already have, which means no changes except adding the following code...

```
foreach ( $menuHead as $menu )  {
    $menu['data'] = array_values($menu['data']);
}
$final['MenuList'] = array_values($menuHead);
```

Comment: This solution didnt work out. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: I've added a new way at the bottom of the answer, this should be used with your original code.

Comment: Yes I did change it in 3 places

Comment: You may need `$menuHead as &$menu` to allow it to update the original data, see if it helps.

Comment: foreach ( $menuHead as $menu )  {
    $menu['data'] = array_values($menu['data']);
}
$final['MenuList'] = array_values($menuHead);


Added this but it didnt work out

Comment: try with `foreach ( $menuHead as &$menu ) ` (i.e. plus the `&`

Comment: This somehow worked out but now I am facing a different issue. Same menuhead contains only 2 datas. please check the screenshot http://prntscr.com/lgkznq

Answer (score 1):

Use  array_values();

I fixed your code, it should work

```
    $menuHead=array(); 
    $i=0; 
    foreach($res as $key => $value){ 
        $i=$key+1;
        //$menuHead[$i]['menuHead']=$value['category'];
        if(isset($menuHead[$key]['menuHead'])){
            if($menuHead[$key]['menuHead']==$value['category']){
              $menuHead[$key]['data'][$i]['itemName']=$value['sub_category'];
              $menuHead[$key]['data'][$i]['price']=$value['price'];
              $menuHead[$key]['data'][$i]['description']=$value['description'];
              $menuHead[$key]['data'][$i]['itemId']=$value['id'];
              $menuHead[$key]['data'][$i]['customizable']=$value['customizable'];
            }else{
              $menuHead[$i]['menuHead']=$value['category'];
              $menuHead[$i]['data'][$i]['itemName']=$value['sub_category'];  
              $menuHead[$i]['data'][$i]['price']=$value['price'];
              $menuHead[$i]['data'][$i]['description']=$value['description'];
              $menuHead[$i]['data'][$i]['itemId']=$value['id'];
              $menuHead[$i]['data'][$i]['customizable']=$value['customizable'];
            }
        }else{
          $menuHead[$i]['menuHead']=$value['category'];
          $menuHead[$i]['data'][$i]['itemName']=$value['sub_category'];  
          $menuHead[$i]['data'][$i]['price']=$value['price'];
          $menuHead[$i]['data'][$i]['description']=$value['description'];
          $menuHead[$i]['data'][$i]['itemId']=$value['id'];
          $menuHead[$i]['data'][$i]['customizable']=$value['customizable'];
        }    
    }
// i'am use array_values()
    $final['MenuList']= array_values($menuHead);
    echo json_encode($final);
```

Comment: Your code added the array in menulist which my code was missing but the data object must also be an array. Kindly help on this

Comment: $final['MenuList']= (object) array_values($menuHead)

Comment: No it didnt work. data json object must also be an array

Comment: Try this.
$final['MenuList'][] = array_values($menuHead);